# Rails stripe_event gem issue: uninitialized constant Stripe::SignatureVerificationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the stripe gem and stripe_event gem in a Rails 4.0.6 application using Ruby 2.1.5. It has been working well until I tried either the 'Securing your webhook endpoint' or 'Authenticating webhooks' section of the stripe_event gem readme (https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event#authenticating-webhooks). It seems both issues have similar behavior so I will just describe the second one here.

When I try to authenticate my webhook (which worked fine before trying this) with the following code, I get an uninitialized constant error.

```
#config/initializers/stripe.rb

Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]

#this is the line that supposedly tells stripe_event to verify the stripe signature    
StripeEvent.signing_secret = ENV['STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET'] 

StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  events.all do |event|
    if event.type == 'invoice.payment_failed'
      #handled this event...removed code for clarity since works fine
    end
  end
end
```

This is the error:

```
NameError stripe_event/webhook#event
uninitialized constant Stripe::SignatureVerificationError
```

I got the stripe signing secret from my stripe dashboard as described in the stripe docs: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#signatures

I have been testing triggering the event as described in the stripe docs: https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/sending-emails-for-failed-payments#testing

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your stripe gem. It will start working.

Comment: That did the trick! Makes total sense in hindsight given the error message